# Inductance of a toroidal electromagnet with a gap

Tags: magnetic-fields, inductance

Suppose we have a toroidal electromagnet of length $l$ and section $A\ll d^2$, with an air gap of width $h\ll d$ with a wire turned $N$ times around it. Suppose we also know that for a large interval of values of $H$, $\mu_r \sim \text{const}.$ I would like to compute the inductance of this object.

**My attempt**

The inductance of a conductor is defined as

$$
L = N\frac{\Phi(i)}{i}
$$

if the solenoid was in void, we would have that $L = \frac{\mu_0 N^2 A}{d}$, while if we have a core inside, then $L = \frac{\mu N^2A}{d}$.

Now I would like to compute the inductance for the system with the gap, so I assume them to be two separate systems and since the current is the same for both they behave as if they were in parallel, then $L = L_{core}+L_{gap}$. Then the two inductances can be found

$$\begin{cases}L_{core} = \Big[\frac{d-h}{d}N\Big]\frac{\Phi(i)}{i} \\
L_{gap} = \Big[\frac{h}{d}N\Big]\frac{\Phi(i)}{i}
\end{cases}$$

where we can use the auxiliary field $H$ to find the magnetic field $B$ (which is the same inside the core and outside if the gap is very thin) and hence the flux $\Phi(i)$ to put inside these formulas.

**My question**

Basically is it right to treat this system as the two systems in parallel and find the total inductance by simply adding the two inductances?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct. An alternative way to see this is to use
the equivalent magnetic energy definition of the inductance.
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} Li^2 =\frac{1}{2} \int d^3r \vec B\cdot \vec H
\end{equation}
As you say, the $\vec B$ field forms loops and since the normal
component must be constant, it has the same value in the gap
as in the material. $H$ will be $B/\mu_0$ in the gap and $B/\mu$ in
the material. So the energy equation with your approximations gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} Li^2 =\frac{1}{2} A B \left [\frac{hB}{\mu_0}+\frac{(d-h)B}{\mu}
\right]
\end{equation}
where the quantity in the bracket is $H$ integrated around the loop.
However, this integral is $Ni$, by Ampere's law, so
\begin{equation}
Ni = \frac{hB}{\mu_0}+\frac{(d-h)B}{\mu}
\,.
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} Li^2 =\frac{1}{2} A B Ni
\end{equation}
which is your equation. You can
solve for $B$ to get
\begin{equation}
B =  \frac{Ni\mu\mu_0}{d\mu_0+h(\mu-\mu_0)} \,,
\end{equation}
and plug this in.

So you can think of the addition as just adding different parts of the magnetic energy integral.